# Inserting image(blob) into mysql database using php prepared statments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I need to insert a image into mysql database using prepared statments... everything else is inserting besides image

```php
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['category']);
    $privacy = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['privacy']);
    $maxmembers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['maxmembers']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
    $file = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name =addslashes($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO hjuma_groups (name, description, category, privacy, maxmembers, owner, avatarname, avatar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
              echo "SQL error";
            }else {
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssssssb", $name,$description,$category, $privacy,$maxmembers, $owner, $image_name, $image);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }
```

Comment: Remove all `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `addslashes`. You don't need to do that since you're using parameterized prepared statements.

Comment: Btw, you don't want to store the files `tmp_name` in the database. You should move the file to a proper location, with a proper file name and store _that_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the piece of the puzzle you were missing is `base64_encode` on the image data, sa below:

```
$name =             $_POST['name']);
$category =         $_POST['category'];
$privacy =          $_POST['privacy'];
$maxmembers =       $_POST['maxmembers']);
$description =      $_POST['description']);
$name =             $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$image_name =       $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
$image =            base64_encode( file_get_contents( $image_name ) );
$image_size =       getimagesize( $image_name );



$sql = "insert into `hjuma_groups` 
        ( `name`, `description`, `category`, `privacy`, `maxmembers`, `owner`, `avatarname`, `avatar`) 
        values 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if( !mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt, $sql ) ) {
    echo "SQL error";
}else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "sssssssb", $name, $description, $category, $privacy, $maxmembers, $owner, $image_name, $image );
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the type flag `b` for the `$image` variable in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` indicate that the OP wants to store it as binary data (blob)? Afaik, you don't need to encode binary data before storing it in a blob?

Comment: it worked before i started doing prepared statments

Comment: is it porblem if i dont do image inside prepared statment, i tried without that and it worked...

```php
      $sql = "INSERT INTO hjuma_groups (name, description, category, privacy, maxmembers, owner, avatarname, avatar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '$image')";
```

Comment: @JurajJaušovec - Why are you storing the images in the database to begin with? Images are files and should, except from some special cases, be stored in the file system instead.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to insert your image by encoding into base64_encode it can easily work by doing like this

```
$image=file_get_contents($_FILES['your_image_name']['tmp_name']);
```

and then in your prepared statement you need to insert data like this

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
```

Insert image as storing in blob data table.

and then display it in your web page like this

```
<?php 
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['your_blob_image_table']) . '" alt="" />';

?>
```

Note: mysqli_escape_real_string and addslashes will make problem in prepared statements kindly don't use it.
If you like my answer then kindly place my answer on number 1.Thanks